# How to Concatenate strings with "," ( Comma ) Delimiter only when the string values are not null using xslt2.0

Tags: xslt, concatenation, notnull

For Eg: Street, BuildingId, FloorId, UnitId needs to be separated with `,` only when the values are not null. If any of the fields is null do not separate with a comma.

```
 <ADDRESS nil="true"><xsl:value-of select="//street"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//buildingId"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//floorId"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//unitId"/></ADDRESS>
```

Comment: <ADDRESS><xsl:value-of select="//street"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//buildingId"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//floorId"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="//unitId"/></ADDRESS_LINE2>

Comment: you have to indent tags to make them visible in question

Comment: So what is a `null` value? If you are using XSLT 2 then you can use the `separator` attribute of `xsl:value-of` e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="foo, bar, baz" separator=","/>` instead of explicitly outputting a separator with `xsl:text`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't think it's that simple: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWmuiHS

Comment: It will depend on what a null value is (my guess was https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRu) but in any case using `separator` instead explicit `<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>` seems more compact in any case for XSLT 2 or 3.

Comment: @MartinHonnen You are right that `null` is ambiguous, but in this case I think it's safe to bet the elements ("fields" in OP words) will  always be there (apparently this is a DB export).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(street, buildingId, floorId, unitId)[string()]" separator=","/>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWmuiHS/1

---

### Added:

> Is it possible to add a space between the attributes if any of the field is blank?

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="for $i in (street, buildingId, floorId, unitId) return if (string($i)) then $i else ' ' " separator=","/>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/gWmuiHS/3

Comment: Wow Michael, thank you very much it is working as I expected.

Comment: Hi Michael, Is it possible to add a space between the attributes if any of the field is blank?

Comment: @RajeshKumar See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last requirement.

Comment: Thank you Michael again for your prompt response.